# What is her name?

Tags: riddle

I stand before her, with calm nervosity
No sweat, but still hot
"Is it me or just the **weather**?" I think

I keep asking myself if I should
I definitely **can**, so I ask
"What's your name, **young lady**?"

Comment: First time hearing the word *nervosity*. (I have heard of nervousness, but the former word sounds better, actually :P)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it

> **May?**

That would make sense, because

> The weather usually starts to get hot (but maybe not hot enough to cause sweat) in **May**,
>  you definitely **may** ask,
>  and **May** is not an uncommon name for a young lady.

Comment: I was half a world away from understanding this question, all that effort 'equated' to nothing =P